# VS Code mouse hover preview for css variables

Tags: css, visual-studio-code

### Is there a way to preview CSS variables values in VS Code?

---

This is how it looks like when using [Tailwind CSS IntelliSense](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bradlc.vscode-tailwindcss)

and that is what I would like to happen with CSS variables.

[image]

This is what actually happens when going Hover with my mouse on CSS variables:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try [this one](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=phoenisx.cssvar) and then look into the CSS variables.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! it doesn't work for me by just installing. Do you know if I need to configure something in VS Code user settings?